# how use attachdbfilename in visual studio c#, to acces in my database.mdf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

I use this link to connect to my database in visual studio "c#"
[image]

```
 SqlConnection direction = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ira\Desktop\hiver 2016\mecatronique\CGC-DOMOTICS\CGC-DOMOTICS\BaseDeDonnées\BDD.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
```

But if I use my program on another desktop, I get an error.

I need help please, my error is in the link to access my database.

Comment: Your code connects to a local database. Logically if you use a different computer the local database doesn't exist (unless you put it in the exact same place) so you will get an error

Comment: yes i know that, but how to use relative path or absolut path. i want to give him a global path.

Comment: so why you use mdf database? SQL Database Instance on SQL Server Express wouldn't be better?

Comment: In that case this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193746/can-sql-server-express-localdb-be-connected-to-remotely and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355332/can-i-connect-to-localdb-mdf-file-on-computer-from-a-web-app-that-is-being-run-o and the short answer is **you can't**

Answer (score 0):

use datadirectory as shown below. for web applications this would be App_Data folder for windows forms it would be user application data directory

```
 SqlConnection direction = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|BDD.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: i use this database for desktop application.
your code give this result : 
`
Une exception non gérée du type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' s'est produite dans System.Data.dll`


`Informations supplémentaires : An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\ira\Desktop\hiver 2016\mecatronique\CGC-DOMOTICS\CGC-DOMOTICS\bin\Debug\BDD.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share`

Comment: If you use data directory when you install application in another machine you need to place this file in applicationdata folder using clickonce publish project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try
"AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath+"\BaseDeDonnes\BDD.mdf"

Comment: ` Gravité Code Description Projet Fichier Ligne Source État de la suppression
Erreur CS0117 'Application' ne contient pas de définition pour 'StartupPath' `

Comment: you can use 'System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location' in wpf instead of Application.StartupPath